# Pivot pandas dataframe from single row to one row per item

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, unnest

I recently applied a transformation to unnest a nested json, in order to have a flat dataset to work with, and while the transformation works, the final format is not the one I am looking for. It compressed all the data into a single row and added suffixes to column names, instead of separating into different columns for each `id_prop`.

My dataset in JSON format to replicate with Pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd
json = {"id_prop.0":{"0":1},"id_prop.1":{"0":2},"id_prop.2":{"0":3},"prop_number.0":{"0":123},"prop_number.1":{"0":325},"prop_number.2":{"0":754},"prop_value.0":{"0":1},"prop_value.1":{"0":1},"prop_value.2":{"0":1}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json, orient='columns')
```

#### My result:

|  | id_prop.0 | id_prop.1 | id_prop.2 | prop_number.0 | prop_number.1 | prop_number.2 | prop_value.0 | prop_value.1 | prop_value.2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 123 | 325 | 754 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

#### The result I expect:

|  | id_prop | prop_number | prop_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 123 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 325 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 754 | 1 |

*Is there any way to pivot the dataframe into the format I need, where each row represents the values of a single `id_prop`?*

#### Attemps

I have already extracted the names of the columns I need without suffixes:

```py
def extract_cols(columns):
    myset = set()
    myset_add = myset.add
    return [x for x in columns if not (x in myset or myset_add(x))]

cols = extract_cols(df.columns.str.replace("\.[0-9]", "", regex=True))
```

And also "verticalized" the results I need using `stack()`:

```py
df_stacked = df.stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```

But I haven't figured out how to combine that info yet. Any help would be highly appreciated.

##### Extra:

**If there is also a way to apply this using pyspark, then much better!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way:

```py
df = df.T
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[x[x.find('.')+1:] for x in df.index], [x[:x.find('.')] for x in df.index]])
df = df.unstack()
```

Input:

```
   id_prop.0  id_prop.1  id_prop.2  prop_number.0  prop_number.1  prop_number.2  prop_value.0  prop_value.1  prop_value.2
0          1          2          3            123            325            754             1             1             1
```

Output:

```
  id_prop prop_number prop_value
0       1         123          1
1       2         325          1
2       3         754          1
```

Explanation:

- transpose so we can work with the index instead of the columns
- parse each label into the desired label (prefix) and the result number (suffix) split by the `.` character
- update the df's index to be a MultiIndex with two levels: an list of result numbers and a list of desired labels
- call `unstack` to pivot a level of the MultiIndex (the desired labels) to be column headings

---

**UPDATE**: To handle labels where result number is the second `.` separated token with additional tokens to its right (as described in OP's comment), we can do this:

```py
import pandas as pd
json = {
    "building.0.description.bedrooms":{"0":"qrs"}, 
    "building.1.description.bedrooms":{"0":"tuv"}, 
    "building.2.description.bedrooms":{"0":"xyz"}, 

    "id_prop.0":{"0":1},"id_prop.1":{"0":2},"id_prop.2":{"0":3},
    "prop_number.0":{"0":123},"prop_number.1":{"0":325},"prop_number.2":{"0":754},
    "prop_value.0":{"0":1},"prop_value.1":{"0":1},"prop_value.2":{"0":1}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json, orient='columns')
print(df.to_string())

df = df.T
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[x.split('.')[1] for x in df.index], ['.'.join(x.split('.')[0:1] + x.split('.')[2:]) for x in df.index]])
df = df.unstack()
df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(1)
print(df)
```

Input:

```
  building.0.description.bedrooms building.1.description.bedrooms building.2.description.bedrooms  id_prop.0  id_prop.1  id_prop.2  prop_number.0  prop_number.1  prop_number.2  prop_value.0  prop_value.1  prop_value.2
0                             qrs                             tuv                             xyz          1          2          3            123            325            754             1             1             1
```

Output:

```
  building.description.bedrooms id_prop prop_number prop_value
0                           qrs       1         123          1
1                           tuv       2         325          1
2                           xyz       3         754          1
```

Comment: Added: one of my real columns is named "building.0.description.bedrooms", "building.1.description.bedrooms", etc... Your code works perfectly, except for those special cases, that are condensed into a single column named "building". How would you proceed then? (sorry for not adding those exceptions before)

Comment: Please see my updated answer for the way to handle such column labels.

Comment: @Tinchosawa Do you need any additional help with your question?

Comment: @Tinchosawa Please consider marking one of the answers as "accepted" if your question has been addressed.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the columns to a multiindex and then stack it:

```py
df.set_axis(
    pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([tuple(i) for i in df.columns.str.split(".")]), axis=1
).stack().droplevel(0)
```